# Fun with linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list

```
int[] vX = verteX.clone();
int[] vY = verteY.clone();
int[] vC = vCost.clone();
int size = vY.length;
for (int i = 0, check = vY[0]; i < size; i++, check = vY[i]) {
    LinkedList<Edge> v = new LinkedList<Edge>();
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (vY[j] == check) {
            Edge e = new Edge();
            e.setY(vX[j]);
            e.setCost(vC[j]);
            v.add(e);
            for (int k = j; k < size - 1; vX[k] = vX[k + 1], vY[k] = vY[k + 1], vC[k] = vC[k + 1], k++)
                ;
            size--;
        }
    }
    i -= 1;
}
```

The three vectors each have the same number of elements.`vX`,`vY` store each the endpoints of an edge and for each vertex from `vX` I'm looking for all the edges starting in that vertex and put them into a `Edge` structure which contains the ending vertex and the cost of that edge.Later I will be adding them into a map but right now I have a problem where the linked list isn't creating correctly and I can't find what I miss.

> vX: 1 2 3 1 1 4 2
>
> vY: 3 5 2 5 2 3 3
>
> vC: 2 1 3 2 4 4 9

For the data above,I get the edges below.The wrong one is [3,2] which is supposed to be in the same group with the other edges starting in vertex 3 but it's evaluated last.I keep looking at it and I don't see the cause for that skip,can you track it down?

> [3,1] [3,4] [5,2] [5,1] [2,3] [2,1] [3,2]

Comment: did the pen&paper and found out that the problem usually occurs when more elements with the same value are next to eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Needed a `=` in the second for,it seemed like it wasn't reaching the last element of the list

```
for(int j=0;j<=size;j++)
```